# Angles between n vectors - Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

Consider a set of points (just an example)

```
x = [0 1 2 5 4 8 5 6];
y = [5 8 4 2 5 6 4 5];
```

and another reference point:

```
xc=1;
yc=1;
```

In which I use to represent these points as vectors:

```
vec=[x-xc y-yc];
```

I wish to obtain a matrix with all the angles between all vectors which is obtained by the calculation (for single vectors)

```
angle = acosd(dot(v,u)/norm(u)*norm(v));
```

How can I obtain this calculation in a few lines without going vector by vector in a loop? In my calculation the number of points is very very large.

Comment: How are `u`, `v` related to `x`, `y`, `xc`, `yc`? What are those "all vectors" for which you want to compute the angle?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you mean `vec = [x-xc; y-yc];`. To calucate the dotproduct between all rows, you can use

```
vec.'*vec
```

The norm (Euclidean) of each vector can be determined as

```
no = sqrt(sum(vec.*vec,1))
```

The product of the different norms can be calculated the same as for `vec`:

```
no.'*no
```

The angles can thus be found as

```
no = sqrt(sum(vec.*vec,1));
angles = acosd(vec.'*vec./(no.'*no));
```